# Kibana shows different date from original document

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I have folloving issue

Elastic mapping:

```json
...  
"logtime" : {
          "type":"date",
          "format":"YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,SSS"     
        }
...
```

Elastic document:

```json
PUT nifi_test_test/_doc/1
{
  "logtime" :"2022-01-12 14:42:07,786"
}
```

Kibana output :

```json
{
  "_index": "nifi_test_test",
  "_type": "_doc",
  "_id": "1",
  "_version": 1,
  "_score": 1,
  "_source": {
    "logtime": "2022-01-12 14:42:07,786"
  },
  "fields": {
    "logtime": [
      "2022-01-03T14:42:07.786Z"
    ]
  }
}
```

Elastic output from query:

```json
...     
 {
        "_index" : "nifi_test_test",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "1",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "logtime" : "2022-01-12 14:42:07,786"
        }
      }
...
```

Kibana Index pattern[Index pattern for date field](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Ov9l.png)

Kibana Discover:
[Discover date](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IkmLt.png)

I wonder why in elastic I see correct date - the same as document, but in Kibana day in date  always = 3 ?

Thank you in advance

Comment: What happens if you try to insert different dates? What version are you of Elastic and Kibana are you using?

Comment: Elastic  7.15.1
Kibana 7.15

`PUT nifi_test_test/_doc/2`
`{`
  `"logtime" :"2022-01-21 10:02:03,006"`
`}`

Kibana JSON output:
`{`
  `"_index": "nifi_test_test",`
  `"_type": "_doc",`
  `"_id": "2",`
  `"_version": 1,`
  `"_score": 1,`
  `"_source": {`
    `"logtime": "2022-01-21 10:02:03,006"`
  `},`
  `"fields": {`
    `"logtime": [`
      `"2022-01-03T10:02:03.006Z"`
    `]`
  `}`
`}`

Again Kibana shows 2022-01-03T10:02:03.006 instead of 2022-01-21 10:02:03,006

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the format:

```json
{"format": "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,SSS"}
```

YYYY is a [week based year](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/temporal/WeekFields.html#:%7E:text=week%2Dbased%2Dyear)

See [DateTimeFormatter docs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-date-format.html#custom-date-formats) also help you!

Comment: Thanks a lot you. It works!